# Why does this formula break after 31 loops?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math, floating-point, formula

I have the following code:

```
public float SnapValueToCoreBlock(float ValueToSnap)
{
    ValueToSnap = ValueToSnap + 0.5f;
    ValueToSnap = Mathf.Floor(ValueToSnap);
    return ValueToSnap;
}

float floatvar;
int intvar;


    for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
    {

        floatvar = z + (Mathf.FloorToInt(0.499999f) + 1) * 0.499999f / (Mathf.FloorToInt(0.499999f) + 1);
        intvar = (int)SnapValueToCoreBlock(floatvar);
    }
```

I am expecting "intvar" to always be equal to "z" in the loop, however after 31 iterations there is some kind of rounding error and when z=32 intvar = 33, instead of z=32 intvar =32

from then onwards intvar is always off by 1, so for  z<32 intvar=z and for z >31 intvar=z+1

my intended result is for z = intvar always, I dont understand why this arbitrarily changes when z reaches 32, I would appreciate it if someone could help me, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could be rounding issue, once you get to 32 your decimal places force it to round up a number.  If you get to 64 or something is it off by 2?  Maybe test your value without casting and see what it is at your 31 number and see if it would round up.

Comment: for 64 its still off by 1, so z=64 gives intvar=65, for z=99 intvar =100, and floatvar always shows z.5, that is for z=1 floatvar = 1.5, and for z = 70 floatvar = 70.5

Comment: I threw 64 out as a guess, maybe at 70 or 80, or whatever the calculations could cause it to round up when you cast it.  I would debug and step through to look at all the numbers on our 31st look and then after to see if one of them could be causing a rounding issue (stil not sure if this is it, but something to look at since your casting your float to int).

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Do you have a good understanding of how floating point numbers work?  On what basis are you _expecting_  things to work the way you expect them to work?

Comment: Print `ValueToSnap` to at least 9 significant decimal places in various parts of  `SnapValueToCoreBlock` to see why.

Comment: if I shave off 1 decimal from 0.499999f to 0.49999f it starts to work as intended, I just wondered why it broke specifically at 32

Comment: "there is some kind of rounding error" contributors include 1) inexact converting `0.499999f` to a `float` 2) inexact `float` multiply and division, 3) inexact `float` addition.  The only math operation done exactly is `Mathf.Floor(ValueToSnap)` and the `(int)` cast.  Printing out the `float` value to at least 9 significant digits after each step will hint why codes behaves as it does.

Comment: What is this `0.4999999` good for at all? If you hardcode this using `FloorToInt` why not simply use `0`? And then why not divide by a clean `0.5f`? And why not simply always use `(int)` instead?

Comment: I mean maybe I'm missing something but how I see it both your `FloorToInt` will always be `0` so basically you could simply wrote it as `floatvar = z + (0+1) * 0.499999f / (0+1);` which equals `floatvar = z + 0.4999999f;` so you could simply wrote it as a clean `floatvar = z + 0.5f;` ... Or not?

Comment: the 0.4999999 is a variable that I am using for collisions, i posted it as 0.4999999 in this case for a reproductible case and for simplicity in narrowing down the problem. This value was working well until it wasn't. There are cases where it would be 1.499 or 2.7 etc

Comment: If you want to work with floats, you can't be using numbers like `0.4999999f`.  Remember, floats only have 6-9 digits of precision, you have 7 there.

Comment: I edited my answer, if you are interested

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took your code and translated them from Unity to the .NET Framework.  This involved changing `Mathf.FloorToInt(someFloat)` to `(int)Math.Floor(someFloat)` and `Mathf.Floor(ValueToSnap)` to `(float)Math.Floor(ValueToSnap)`.  I believe it does the same thing, but it takes a detour through `double`.

I also inserted a WriteLine statement in your loop:

```
for (int z = 0; z < 100; z++)
{
    floatvar = z + ((int)Math.Floor(0.499999f) + 1) * 0.499999f / ((int)Math.Floor(0.499999f) + 1);
    intvar = (int)SnapValueToCoreBlock(floatvar);
    Debug.WriteLine($"FloatVar: {floatvar} Z: {z} IntVar: {intvar}");
}
```

I see the same behaviour.

In particular, I see breaks at `z` == 9:

```
FloatVar: 8.499999 Z: 8 IntVar: 8
FloatVar: 9.499999 Z: 9 IntVar: 9
FloatVar: 10.5 Z: 10 IntVar: 10
FloatVar: 11.5 Z: 11 IntVar: 11
```

and at `z` == 32:

```
FloatVar: 30.5 Z: 30 IntVar: 30
FloatVar: 31.5 Z: 31 IntVar: 31
FloatVar: 32.5 Z: 32 IntVar: 33
FloatVar: 33.5 Z: 33 IntVar: 34
```

Even if I extend the precision of the output beyond the precision of the float:

```
Debug.WriteLine($"FloatVar: {floatvar:0.0000000000000000000} Z: {z} IntVar: {intvar}");
```

I see the same behaviour, rounding down below 32 and rounding up above it.

Then I greatly simplified your calculation:

```
floatvar2 = z + 0.499999f;
intvar2 = (int)SnapValueToCoreBlock(floatvar2);
```

And I still see the same behaviour.

So, what it seems is that:

```
 anInteger + 0.499999f + 0.5f;
```

is less than `anInteger + 1.0f` for values of `anInteger < 32` and equal to or greater than `anInteger + 1.0f` for values `anInteger >= 32`.  And, you know what, that doesn't surprise me.  You are right at the edge of floating point precision (remember, floats have ~6-9 digits of precision: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/floating-point-numeric-types).  When you went from 31 to 32, you ended up setting another bit, and that's what likely made the difference.

**Final Comment** *(as an update)*

You say *"the 0.4999999 is a variable that I am using for collisions"*.  You need to read up on how to compare floating point values, and how to properly use an *epsilon*.  Here's one thing I found (https://bitbashing.io/comparing-floats.html).  It's C++ focused, but seems to address the issues.  As a final comment, if you are ever using measured values (like in a chemical process control system), you need to include the precision of your measurements in the establishment of an *epsilon*.